# JSON для TreeTable в PRIME NG

Tags: javascript, json

Как лучше сгенерить такой JSON?

```
let main = {

  "data": [{
      "data": {
        "name": "zzzzzz"
      },
      "children": [{
          "data": {
            "name": "Test1"
          }
        },
        {
          "data": {
            "name": "Test2"
          }
        },
        {
          "data": {
            "name": "Test3"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "data": {
        "name": "zzzzzzz"
      },
      "children": [{
          "data": {
            "name": "Test1"
          }
        },
        {
          "data": {
            "name": "Test2"
          }
        },
        {
          "data": {
            "name": "Test3"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Сделал свой вариант, но он далек от оптимального. Спасибо!

```
let arrr = [];
let arrr2 = [];
let objData3 = {};
let objData4 = {};

for (let itemz in arr) {
  let a = arr[itemz];

  let objNameInData = {};
  let objNameInData2 = {};
  let startObj = {};
  startObj.name = a.ServiceName;

  objNameInData.name = startObj;
  objNameInData2.name = "zzzzz"

  let objDataInChildren = {};
  let objDataInData = {};


  objDataInChildren.data = objNameInData.name;
  arrr.push(objDataInChildren);
  objData3.data = objNameInData2;
  objData3.children = arrr;
  arrr2.push(objData3)
  objData4.data = arrr2;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(objData4, null, 4))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так я себе это увидел -

**Вариант 1**

```js
const createJSON = count => Object.create(Object.prototype, {
  data: {
    value: Array.from(Array(count).keys(),e=>Object.create(Object.prototype,{
      data: {
        value: Object.create(Object.prototype,{
          name: {
            value: "zzzzzz",
            writable: true,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
          }
        }),
        writable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
      },
      children: {
        value: Array.from(Array(3).keys(),(e,i)=>Object.create(Object.prototype,{
          data: {
            value: Object.create(Object.prototype,{
              name: {
                value: `Test ${i+1}`,
                writable: true,
                enumerable: true,
                configurable: true
              }
            }),
            writable: true,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
          }
        })),
        writable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
      }
    })),
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
  }
});
let main = createJSON(2);
console.log(main)
```

**Вариант 2**

```js
const createJSON = count => Object.create(Object.prototype, {
  data: {
    value: Array.from(Array(count).keys(),e=>JSON.parse('{"data":{"name":"zzzzzz"},"children":[{"data":{"name":"Test1"}},{"data":{"name":"Test2"}},{"data":{"name":"Test3"}}]}')),
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
  }
});
let main = createJSON(2);
console.log(main)
```